# jQuery DataTables clear table except the first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables. I want to clear table except the first row.

```
 var table = $('tableId').DataTable({});
```

Sample:
tr1
tr2
tr3

```
table.clear().draw(); //This clear all rows, How do I exclude first row
```

clear table:
tr1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this - I've used `.rows().remove()` instead of `.clear()`, so I could select which rows should be removed.

```
$('#deleteAll').click(function(){
    //get first element
    var firstElement = $('tbody > tr').first();

    /*remove all <tr> which are coming after the first element and
    redraw the table */
    table.rows(firstElement.nextAll('tr')).remove().draw();
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0huyj9jp/1/)**